# Medalha Eleitorado com descrição ambígua

Tags: debate, medalhas

> [image: Screenshot da tag com sua descrição]

A [medalha **Eleitorado**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/electorate) tem uma descrição ambígua: *"Vote em 600 perguntas, com pelo menos 25% dos votos totais indo para perguntas"*.

Se o voto é em perguntas, claro que os 25% vão para perguntas! Eu entendi errado ou essa descrição está mesmo ruim?

Ou talvez signifique "Vote em 600 perguntas, sendo que, do **seu total de votos**, 25% deve ter ido para perguntas" ou algo similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realmente é confuso. Se verificarmos no [FAQ do meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/401803), lá é explicado o critério exato:

- Votar em 600 **perguntas**
- Do seu **número total de votos** (dados em perguntas **e** respostas), pelo menos 25% deles devem ter sido em perguntas

O mesmo FAQ também dá alguns exemplos. Na tabela abaixo, "Total" é o número total de votos dados (tanto em perguntas quanto em respostas) e "%" é a porcentagem dos votos que foram dados em perguntas (ou seja, `("Perguntas" / "Total") * 100`).

| Perguntas | Respostas | Total | % | Ganhou a medalha? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 600 | 2400 | 3000 | 20% | Não, porcentagem baixa |
| 201 | 401 | 602 | ~33% | Não; < 600 perguntas |
| 599 | 0 | 599 | 100% | Não; < 600 perguntas |
| 600 | 0 | 600 | 100% | Sim |
| 500 | 500 | 1000 | 50% | Não; < 600 perguntas |
| 650 | 650 | 1300 | 50% | Sim |

---

Então qual seria uma descrição melhor? Não sou muito bom nisso, mas algumas opções seriam:

- Votar em 600 perguntas, sendo que estes correspondem a 25% do total de votos dados (*é apenas uma variação da opção dada na pergunta*).
- Ter 25% dos seus votos dados em perguntas, e pelo menos 600 votos em perguntas.

Ou algo assim...

Comment: Outra opção é traduzir o FAQ :-)

Comment: sim :) mas a descrição da medalha acho que é pequena, difícil explicar isso